# Reverse of an array Hackerrank

Tags: c++

This is a syntax of a program that I made of hackerrank to reverse an array. The location of the question is Practice < Data Structures < Arrays < Arrays - DS
the program seems to work fine on an online compiler but is showing error over hackerrank.
can anyone guide me where I went wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main(){
    int n,i;
    int arr[n];
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];

    }
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            cout<<arr[i];
        }
}
```

Comment: You must read `n` before creating `int arr[n];`. Also, variable-length arrays (aka arrays with size not known at compile-time) are not a part of the standard C++, and might not work on some compilers.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an array with n elements before you read n, i.e n is having garbage value. Here is correct working code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
int main(){
    int n,i;
   cout<<"Enter number of elements"<<endl; // Comment it if you don't want debug console outut
    cin>>n;
     int arr[n];
     cout<<"Enter "<<n<<" elements"<<endl; // Comment it if you don't want debug  console outut
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];

    }
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            cout<<arr[i];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your solution and it work fine now , i will tell you some notes for your future:

1 - You have to read size of array first before declare array as mentioned in comments by @[HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) , otherwise it will give garbage value.

2 - this command `int arr[n];` won't work on all Compilers and may give you an Error. Is there a solution to declare array without specific size ? Yes , you can use Vector like that `vector<int> arr(n);`but you have to include library of vector first `#include<vector>`

3 - In C and C++ programs the main function is of type `int` and therefore it should return an integer value. The return value of the main function is considered the "Exit Status" of the application. On most operating systems returning 0 is a success status like saying "The program worked fine". So you have to write `return 0;` in the end of your program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector> // must include to use Vectors
using namespace std; 
int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n; // Must read size of array first , otherwise it will give it garbude value
    vector<int> arr(n);  //  instead of  int arr[n]
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    for(int i = n-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << endl; // to print new line as mentioned in the problem statement 
    return 0; // Prefer to use it always 
}
```

Hope that helps you and Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The exercise of Hacker Rank needs that you reverse an array of integers, might you have a problem with the variable size array, cause some compilers support this characteristic but others not.

And Hacker Rank do not support some properties in other languages like JS , Hacker Rank do not support prompt() for take an input.

In any case for fix this error you can use vector class.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>//Include library vector for dynamic size of array


using namespace std;

int main(){

int n;
cin>>n;

vector<int> arr(n);//Declare the vector with a max size n


for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}

for(int i = n-1 ;i>=0;i--){
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
return 0;
```

}

This code has passed al test cases of hackerRank
[All the test on hackerRank had passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xO5K.png)